# E: Unable to locate package denyhosts

Tags: software-installation, ssh

As I use SSH, I would like to get the `denyhosts` that I read about [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSecurityTools), but when using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install denyhosts
```

To install it, I got this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package denyhosts
```

So is this package no longer available then? Or is it just under a different name or something? If this package is no longer available on the main Ubuntu repositories, is there anywhere else from which I can get it?

OS Information:

```
Description:    Ubuntu 14.10
Release:    14.10
```

Comment: You can install denyhosts but it is not available in software channel, i have added an answer for downloading and installing denyhosts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Denyhosts is no longer available. You can use fail2ban or better, a few ssh tips.

1. Use ssh keys and disable password authentication.
2. iptables can do essentially the same thing as denyhosts and fail2ban . The advantage is no additional packages are required.

   ```
   iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m tcp -m state --state NEW -m recent --set --name SSH --rsource

   iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m recent --update --seconds 600 --hitcount 8 --rttl --name SSH --rsource -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

   iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
   ```

See:

http://bodhizazen.com/Tutorials/SSH_security

http://bodhizazen.com/Tutorials/iptables#Additional_Tips

On the second link, scroll down a bit. You will need to save and restore your iptables rules.

Answer (score 0):

Run the commands below to download version 2.10

```
cd /tmp/ && wget http://cznic.dl.sourceforge.net/project/denyhost/denyhost-2.10/denyhosts-2.10.tar.gz
```

Next, run the commands below to extract it.

```
tar xzf denyhosts*.tar.gz
```

Then run the commands below to change into the extracted folder

```
cd DenyHosts*
```

Finally, run the commands below to install the program

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

After running the commands above, DenyHosts will be installed on your server but not fully configured You must manually configure the tool.

Copy the daemon file to the `/etc/init.d/` directory.

```
sudo cp /usr/local/bin/daemon-control-dist /etc/init.d/denyhosts
```

Next, open the script (`sudo vi /etc/init.d/denyhosts`) and make the below highlighted change

```
###############################################
#### Edit these to suit your configuration ####
###############################################

DENYHOSTS_BIN="/usr/local/bin/denyhosts.py"
DENYHOSTS_LOCK="/run/denyhosts.pid" 
DENYHOSTS_CFG="/etc/denyhosts.conf"

PYTHON_BIN="/usr/bin/env python"
```

Once installed, its configured and ready to protect your servers. One thing most webmasters do is go white-list their own IP address so they don’t get blocked or banned mistakenly.

To white-list your own IP address, open the allow host file in the /etc/ directory and add your IP address you use to connect to the server.

```
sudo vi /etc/hosts.allow
```

Then add your IP address in the file and save it.

```
###############
####Example####
###############

sshd: 172.145.33.45
```

Restart DenyHosts by running the commands below.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/denyhosts start
```

DenyHosts configuration file is at `/etc/denyhosts.conf`.